# How to store values in the database for a complex shopping cart

Tags: php, database

I'm working on a shopping cart with a little bit complex way of storing products in cart.

For each product that a user can add in cart there is a table like this:

[image]

In this table the user enters the quantity for the specified size and color. What would be the best way to store this values in a database table so that I can easily get and display them later?

I'm using PHP and a MySQL database.

Now my table looks like bellow but I'm having trouble getting the values when someone requests more than one size per color.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_platform_cart` (
  `cart_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cart_product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cart_product_name` varchar(256) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `cart_product_photo` varchar(256) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `cart_product_color_name` varchar(128) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `cart_product_color_image` varchar(128) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `cart_product_color` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `cart_product_size` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `cart_product_quantity` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cart_product_price` varchar(12) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `cart_date` date NOT NULL,
  `cart_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`cart_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Thank you.

Comment: How much later would you need to retrieve and display the details? And for what purpose?

Comment: Is the pricing different for different color / size combinations?  That might help determine how your tables are structured.

Comment: DJ Quimby - there's the same price, no matter the color or size.

Comment: Saladin Akara - like in the checkout page.

Comment: You don't need to have all the data like images, names etc in this table. This should be (and probably is) in the products table. So I would recommend just leaving it with a product ID, and use MySQL to retrieve the data stored.
Therefore I think my answer is still the best answer
Calculation of the price should not be in MySQL but rather in PHP

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

Add a new row in the database for each Color/Size combination. So something like this:

```
INSERT INTO chart (user_id,item_id,color,size,quantity,cart_date) VALUES (.....
```

You could also, which might be a better idea, add the Chart items in the `$_SESSION`. This way your database isn't getting polluted

Answer (score 1):

I would normalize this data in the database as pairs.  Have a column for the user, the product, the color, the size, and the quantity ordered.  Each square on the UI you posted would be a row in the database.

That would be flexible as you could easily add more products, colors, sizes, etc.  Querying for a user, a product, colors, etc would all be very easy.

Comment: Thanks for the input Mike. I have edited my post with my current table structure and also with the reason that I don't think this is the best choice.

Comment: Requesting more than one size per color would mean more than one row in the table.  You'd have a row for "Red, size 2" and another row for "Red, size 3"..

Comment: Mike, I agree with you and as you can see my structure is very much like the way to said. But there is a problem when I have someone that has entered quantities for more than one size per color. I don't know how to get that and display it.

Comment: Yea I get what you're saying.  It makes getting and "pivoting" the data more challenging.  I think that logic has to be done in PHP code.  That's more of an algorithm question, you might want to post that as a separate question now that you have the database schema designed..

Comment: I think the main problem is that in the cart page I have to display a text input even for the colors/sizes for witch the user hasn't added any value.

Comment: So you're not only loading cart information, you're loading product information for each distinct item in their cart.  You probably have to first query for all the sizes for each product in the user's cart.  Such as: SELECT Color, Size FROM ProductSkus WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT ProductId FROM site_platform_cart WHERE UserId=123));

Answer (score 1):

Your cart is nothing more than a representation of a sales order, and you should remember this.  You need two tables (at minimum) to represent a sales order: one containing information on the overall order, the other containing information on all of the lines of the order.

Hopefully you have some kind of an 'Items' table, and hopefully each item key is different for each color/size combination (in other words, each color/size combo is a separate product).

If it is, simply store the item number and quantity in the line table for the order as you would in any other store.

Comment: In terms of shopping cart functionality (something I don't have much experience in), how is 'temporary' data stored? I wouldn't think that storing the details in the database is the best way until the order has been confirmed. After all, they might decide to not order, at which point you'd need to delete the 'order' from the database if you insert before confirmation. Or am I on a whole different page here?

Comment: Whether you want to store the data in a database before confirmation or not is a requirement decision.  Some people want to track abandoned orders, in which case you can just have a field, called 'isSubmitted' or something that defaults to 0 and is set to 1 when the order is confirmed.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. While I've dealt with similar issues to this in terms of DB design, I've not really worked on cart functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best way.  I would use a table that stores all possible colors.  A second table to store all possible sizes.  A third order table would contain quantities and references to the size and color tables.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to put in my two cents' worth after deliberating over exactly what you are trying to achieve here.

The most pressing problem, I think, is the way you've designed the database. I had to deal with a similar problem before, and what was finally used as a solution was something like this:

```
table: Colours
    ColourID* | ColourDescription

table: Sizes
    SizeID* | SizeDescription

table: GenericItem
    GenericID* | Item Description | Price | Etc

table: Item
    ItemID* | ParentItem | SizeID | ColourID | AvailableStock | Etc
```

The `Colours` and `Sizes` tables store every size and colour that is available within your produt range.  The `GenericItem` table stores each product you stock. For example, a Joe Bloggs V-Neck T-Shirt. Finally, the `Item` table stores each *unique* item - eg: Large Red Joe Bloggs V-Neck T-Shirt. You give it a unique item ID, and can easily reference the additional information from the `GenericItem` table.

Now, in terms of the cart, you can have tables like such:

```
table: Cart
    CartID* | CartUserID | CartDate | Etc
```

This table would hold the information for each specific cart. And now, expanding on Topener's answer, you would separately hold information for each cart line:

```
table: CartLine
    CartLineID* | CartID | ItemID | Quantity | Etc
```

This way, you an keep your data much more normalised and easily accessible, and allows you to store each cart in the database.

To retrieve this data, all you would need to do is store the `CartID` inside the `$_session` and have all your queries stem from that. For example, to reshow order lines: `SELECT * FROM CartLine WHERE CartID = $_SESSION['CartID']`

To display the grid now, all you need to do is create an array based around something like `SELECT * FROM Item WHERE ParentItem = 'GenericID'`. In this example, I assume that you have the generic item's ID already as a variable somewhere to display all the information about it on the page. Then, you can use the information there to map each textbox to an index of the array.

Hopefully, this will point you in the right direction.